# Python VK_API + KeyBoard

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Подскажите, как можно в данный код добавить inline-кнопки. Данный код скачал, а в vk_api не шарю. Единственное что понял, inline-кнопки можно включить или выключить.

````
import vk_api, json
from config import TOKEN

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = TOKEN)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

clck = 0
number_clck = 0.001

class User:
    def __init__(self, id, mode):
        self.id = id
        self.mode = mode
        self.name = ''
        self.age = -1
        self.clck = 0

def get_keyboard(buts):
    nb = []
    for i in range(len(buts)):
        nb.append([])
        for k in range(len(buts[i])):
            nb[i].append(None)
    for i in range(len(buts)):
        for k in range(len(buts[i])):
            text = buts[i][k][0]
            color = {'зеленый' : 'positive', 'красный' : 'negative', 'синий' : 'primary'}[buts[i][k][1]]
            nb[i][k] = {"action": {"type": "text", "payload": "{\"button\": \"" + "1" + "\"}", "label": f"{text}"}, "color": f"{color}"}
    first_keyboard = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': nb, 'inline' : False}
    first_keyboard = json.dumps(first_keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
    first_keyboard = str(first_keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
    return first_keyboard

def sender(id, text, key):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0, 'keyboard' : key})

clear_key = get_keyboard(
    []
)

click_menu_key = get_keyboard([
    [(' Клик', 'зеленый',)],
    [('Вернуться обратно', 'синий')]
])

menu_key = get_keyboard([
    [('Информация', 'синий')],
    [(' Мой профиль', 'зеленый')],
    [('Заработать', 'красный')]
])

users = []

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:

            id = event.user_id
            msg = event.text.lower()

            if msg == 'начать':
                flag = 0
                for user in users:
                    if user.id == id:
                        flag = 1
                        break
                if flag == 0:
                    users.append(User(id, 'reg1'))
                    sender(id, 'Зарегистрируйтесь в боте.\nВведите своё имя:', clear_key)
                elif flag == 1:
                    for user in users:
                        if user.id == id:
                            if not(user.mode in ['reg1', 'reg2']):
                                sender(id, 'Вы уже зарегистрировались!', menu_key)

            else:
                for user in users:
                    if user.id == id:

                        if user.mode == 'reg1':
                            user.name = msg.title()
                            sender(id, 'Введите свой возраст:', clear_key)
                            user.mode = 'reg2'

                        elif user.mode == 'reg2':
                            try:
                                user.age = int(msg)
                                sender(id, 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!', menu_key)
                                user.mode = 'menu'
                            except:
                                sender(id, 'Значение не подходит!', clear_key)

                        elif user.mode == 'menu':
                            if msg == 'информация':
                                sender(id, f'Данный бот в режиме тестировки.', menu_key)
                            if msg == ' мой профиль':
                                sender(id, f'Ваше имя в боте: {user.name}\nВаш возраст в боте: {user.age}', menu_key)
                            if msg == 'заработать':
                                sender(id, f'Кликайте, чтобы заработать как можно больше!', click_menu_key)
                            if msg == 'вернуть обратно':
                                sender(id, f'Вы вернулись в меню', menu_key)
                            if msg == ' клик':
                                sender(id, f' {user.name}, Ты кликнул(а) и получил {number_clck} руб!\n Твой баланс: {user.clck}\n\n Текущая выплата за один клик: {number_clck} руб. \n\n Продолжай в том же духе!', click_menu_key)
                                user.clck += number_clck```


Заранее спасибо за помощь и Ваши ответы
````